# How to open the TFS "View History" window from a VSPackage?

Tags: envdte, vspackage

I'm writing a VSPackage for Visual Studio that contains a tool window to display a list of items from TFS.  When one of the items is clicked, I'd like to open the "View History" window.  How can this window be opened programmatically?

[image: View History]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll contains this functionality.  I was able to open the history window with the following code:

```
VersionControlExt versionControlExt = dte.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt") as VersionControlExt;
versionControlExt.History.Show("$/Path/To/Item", VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full);
```